# how to implement to get and display the string from arraylist when next button action is done

Tags: android, button, text, view, arraylist

Im new to android..

Im facing a problem in Nextbutton while displaying the next  question...

In my first time set text im getting the correct question and matched four option answers. What i needed is..

I have a nextbutton for displaying the next question and answers..When click on next button i can get the next four options for next question..But i can't get next question after four times i click on next it shows next question...but answers are correct.

What im doing wrong? what im missing?

Any help would be appreciated...Thanks a lot in advance..

> ```
>       protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
>     List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>         System.out.println("cool");
>     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tid", tid));
>     json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_quesurl, "GET", params);
>     System.out.println("ques value got");
>     Log.d("All Groups: ", json.toString());
>         System.out.println("question");
>     try {
>     int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>     System.out.println("Success");
>     if (success == 1) {
>     System.out.println("Success");
>     groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
>     System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
>     for (int i = 0; i < groups.length();i++) {
>     JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
>           String question = c.getString(TAG_QUES);
>       System.out.println("Checking ::"+question);
>     ques1.add(question);
>     String answer = c.getString(TAG_ANSW);
>     System.out.println("Checking ::"+answer);
>     answ1.add(answer);
>            }
>         } else {
>             showAlert();
>         }
>     } catch (JSONException e) {
>         System.out.println("Error "+e.toString());
>     }
>     return null;
> }  
>    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>     pDialog.dismiss();
>       ques1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(ques1));
>             //  j=0;
>             TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
>             txtque.setText(ques1.get(j));
>     answ1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(answ1));
>             btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get(0));
>             btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get(1));
>             btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get(2));
>             btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get(3));
>          btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
>                     RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
>                    // Toast.makeText(Question.this, "" + radioButton.getText(), 2000).show(); 
>                     TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>                     txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText());
>                 }
>     });
>         Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
>         nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
>           public void onClick(View v){  
>           j++;
>         TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
>         txtque.setText(ques1.get(j)); 
>         k++;
>         btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+0));
>         btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+1));
>         btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+2));
>         btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+3));
>          }
>        });
> }
> ```

Comment: make a custom adapter and using that you can get string form array.

Comment: How i cant understand..Can you give some example using my code...im new to android..help me

Comment: where is your question and answer ? using local or web service ?

Comment: webservice...I got question and answer from JSON object and question are stored in ques1 arrayList and answers are stored in answ1 ArrayList..

Comment: Please post the full code i mean how you storing questions?

Comment: where is your json obj ? i mentation in answer like **Question.add(json_data.getString("QUESTION_TAG").toString());** where you have to write add just your json obj.

Comment: @smiley see my full code..help me

Comment: ques1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(ques1));why you again declare the ques1 arraylist in onPostExecute...

Comment: @smiley to store all questions in the arraylist...What changes i want to do? im not getting next question..but im getting next four option answers..help me..

Comment: @smiley please help me..Why im not getting next question..What im doing wrong? but im getting the answers correct...Any mistake in loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are storing answers in answ1 array for that time four empty strings adding in ques1 array so you are getting your next question after four times pressing the button....

For that maintain two indexes one for questions and other for answers..

Comment: yes i maintain two indexes only "j" for question and "k" for answers...Its not getting the next question...What im doing wrong really i dont know please help me..frnd..

Comment: please give ur webservice link for getting questions and answers?

Comment: its not opening in google chrome shows the following error....... Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 10.0.2.2

Comment: How you will open this link, its my path link to file ques_ans1.php. I cant understand your question..What link you need..frnd

Comment: where u getting questions and answers

Comment: TAG_QUES and TAG_ANSW..its JSON object..here im getting question and answer from database through php file ques_ans1

Comment: am asking the phplink when connecting to phpserver ur getting data know that link am asking

Comment: k then post ur response what ur getting?

Comment: k thanks for the help..i got answers in separate phplink and question separate phplink..so now it works..

Comment: @God'sGrace are you using two php link to get question and answer ? don't do that. its not good coding

Comment: @chintankhetiya if in one php link i get question and answers means the questions runs four times...so only i got in separate link..

Comment: @smiley see this link and answer to me help me.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685873/how-to-uncheck-or-clear-the-radiobutton-group

Answer (score 1):

**Make Your Array :**

- `ArrayList<String> Question = new ArrayList<String>();`
- `ArrayList<String> Answer = new ArrayList<String>();`

**Add your value :**

- `Question.add(json_data.getString("QUESTION_TAG").toString());`
- `Answer.add(json_data.getString("ANSWER_TAG").toString());`

check List Length and you have to update index in button click.

**Button Click Event :**

- `Question.get(index).toString();`
- `Answer.get(index).toString();`

Here you can use your data and update index each time after click and if your answer id true.

**Note:**
your index should be maintain otherwise it will throws `indexoutofrangeexception` Exception.

Hope you can manage according to this.

Comment: okay TAG_QUES & TAG_ANSW is your json code. now as you do add data in loop and then get index in button click event. i don't know where you getting issue ?

Comment: See my update...please help me..really i dont know where im doing mistake..what im missing? Im new to android..

Comment: solve your issue or still getting issue ? i have give you upvote

Comment: see this link and answer me help me plz.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685873/how-to-uncheck-or-clear-the-radiobutton-group