# How to uncheck or clear the radiobutton group?

Tags: android, radio-button

I'm new to android..

Im facing a problem in uncheck the radio button in a group....

My problem is....

I am developing an quiz based app. there will be 1 quest and 4 opt(radio buttons) when user opens this app radio button will be unchecked but the prob comes when the user answers 1 quest and when he goes for next quest radio button will be checked.I want to uncheck/reset the radio buttons for every quest.How can i do it?

Another problem which im facing is... If suppose the user selected first button and again he want to change the option so he select another button that time he should not able to select..

How to implement this?

Any help would be appreciated.

> ```
>     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>         pDialog.dismiss();
>      ques1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(ques1));
>         //  j=0;
>         TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
>         txtque.setText(ques1.get(j));
> answ1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(answ1));
>         btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get(0));
>         btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get(1));
>         btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get(2));
>         btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get(3));
>         btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
>                 RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);   // error       
>                                                                           //  is here 205 line..
>                 String temp = radioButton.getText().toString();
>                 crrtans=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(crrtans));
>                 if (temp.equals(crrtans.get(l))){
>                 TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>                 txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + " IS CORRECT");   
>                 txtRadio.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
>             }else{
>                 //RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
>                    // Toast.makeText(Question.this, "" + radioButton.getText(), 2000).show(); 
>                     TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>                     txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + "is INCORRECT");
>                     txtRadio.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
>             }
>             }
>      });
>     Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
>     nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
>       public void onClick(View v){
>     //    btn_practicerg.clearCheck();
>           if (j == ques1.size() -1) {
>                 //finish();
>                 showAlert1();
>             }
>           else{ 
>             ++j;
>             TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
>             txtque.setText(ques1.get(j));
>             ++k;
>             btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+0));
>             btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+1));
>             btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+2));
>             btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+3));
>           }
>           btn_practicerg.clearCheck();
>           btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
>                     RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
>                     String temp = radioButton.getText().toString();
>                     l++;
>                     if (temp.equals(crrtans.get(l))){
>                     TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>                     txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + " IS CORRECT");   
>                     txtRadio.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
>                 }else{
>                     //RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
>                        // Toast.makeText(Question.this, "" + radioButton.getText(), 2000).show(); 
>                         TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>                         txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + " IS INCORRECT");
>                         txtRadio.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
>                 }
>                 }      
>          });
>      }
> });   
>     Button previousbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prv_btn);
>     previousbtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
>     public void onClick(View v){
>         if (j <= 0) {
>             Toast.makeText(Question.this, "First Question",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             } else {
>             --j;
>             TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
>             txtque.setText(ques1.get(j));
>             --k;
>             btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+0));
>             btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+1));
>             btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+2));
>             btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+3));
>             }
>          btn_practicerg.clearCheck();
>          btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
>                     RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
>                     String temp = radioButton.getText().toString();
>                     l--;
>                     if (temp.equals(crrtans.get(l))){
>                     TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>                     txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + " IS CORRECT");   
>                     txtRadio.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
>                 }else{
>                     //RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
>                        // Toast.makeText(Question.this, "" + radioButton.getText(), 2000).show(); 
>                         TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>                         txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText() + " IS INCORRECT");
>                         txtRadio.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
>                 }
>                 }      
>          });
>          }
>     });
>     }
> ```
>
> Logcat

```
            E/AndroidRuntime(893): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            E/AndroidRuntime(893): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:313)
            E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at 
         com.example.finalpractice.Question$LoadQuestions$2$1.onCheckedChanged(Question.java:243)
            E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at 
         android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:172)
            E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:52)
            E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at 
         android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:342)
            E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at 
         android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:127)
            E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at 
         android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:86)
            E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:72)
            E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at 
         android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:98)
            E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            E/AndroidRuntime(893):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

Comment: Any one answer me help me..

Comment: where is Question.java:205 line in code ?

Comment: see above i have mentioned in command line...help me

Comment: have you try `RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)group. findViewById(checkedId);` instead of `RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);`

Comment: yes i tried..i cant clear..what option i have choose the same option is selected in next question also..i cant uncheck...  What im doing wrong please help me..

Comment: When i toggle also i throws error...

Comment: Any one please help me what im doing wrong? what im missing?

Comment: sorry friend but  im not clear about your question . if u really want help then plz explain it as much as possible to get right and quick answer

Comment: I want to check one button at a time..not other buttons..and user goes next question it should rest or uncheck or clearCheck the button....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23902/discussion-between--k-and-godsgrace)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have a radiogroup named `rb` and 2 radiobuttons (`rbY` , `rbN`) inside of it.

---

So, this is my implementation using the `onClickListener`:

```
final RadioGroup rb = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.creditcards);
                RadioButton rbY = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
                RadioButton rbN = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);

                final View finalConvertView = convertView;

                rbY.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int selected = rb.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        RadioButton rbYes = (RadioButton) finalConvertView.findViewById(selected);
                        RadioButton rbN = (RadioButton) finalConvertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);

                        if (rbYes.isSelected()) {
                            rbYes.setSelected(false);
                            rb.clearCheck();
                            rb.clearChildFocus(rbYes);
                        } else {
                            rbYes.setSelected(true);
                        }
                    }
                });

                rbN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int selected = rb.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        RadioButton rbNo = (RadioButton) finalConvertView.findViewById(selected);

                        if (rbNo.isSelected()) {
                            rbNo.setSelected(false);
                            rb.clearCheck();
                            rb.clearChildFocus(rbNo);
                        }
                        else {
                            rbNo.setSelected(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be useful https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/deselectable-radio-button. It's a custom radio button that will allow for you to de-select an option thats already been checked.

Answer (score 1):

Create **clearRadioButtons** method and call in onCreate.

```java
public void clearRadioButtons() {
    radiogroup.clearCheck();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check/uncheck radio button you can use `radioButton.setChecked(true);` (or false to uncheck)

Comment: The method setChecked(boolean) is undefined for the type RadioGroup  it shows error like this...

Comment: It's a method of RadioButton, not RadioGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like find id's for all radio buttons in onCreate() and make it as global...

in the onClickListener of next button write radioButton.setChecked(false); for all your radio buttons what you used...and remove the line btn_practicerg.clearCheck();

i tried like this working fine..

Comment: arrayindexoutofboundexception is for u are getting value beyond that index

Comment: i said remove the line btn_practicerg.clearCheck(); did u do that

Answer (score 0):

To clear the radio button group you can follow this snippet

```
radioGroup.check(-1);
```